# How do I paint over chipped powder coated galvanized steel?

Tags: painting, paint, exterior

I have a metal outdoor structure that is made of galvanized steel and powder coated. A portion of the powder coating has peeled away. The rest appears to be adhering well.

What are the best products/methods to repair the damaged powder coating without the ability to powder coat myself?

Is there a way that I can just remove whatever powder coating isn't adhered well, prime the entire surface including the bare galvanized steel and powder coating, then paint with something that will hold up well as this is exposed to the elements outdoors. Which types of primers, paints and surface prep should I be looking at? I'm hoping there's a way I can get away without stripping the entire piece.

I'm not sure I can match the color and I was never thrilled with the color either so would like to change it.

Comment: Warning: galvanized steel is tough to get paint to adhere to.

Comment: @DanielGriscom well if it were easy I wouldn't be asking :-)

Comment: Sorry; stating the obvious is a skill of mine.

Comment: I've been told in the past to wash/wipe down galvanized metal with vinegar prior to painting to ensure adhesion.